# Not getting job/projects

Tags: freelance-websites

i am fresher on upwork ,so i don'thave ratings on my profile. I tried a lot to get any project/job even at lowest prices but my all proposals are getting rejected . Please suggest me some advice so that I can get projects on upwork .

Answer (score 2):

You have to do one thing: " be patient " and never give-up.  You will surely get a job.  But the problem is, most of the clients will want to give their jobs to an experienced freelancer who has a good record. There you are most likely not to get the job.

- But you will get job from client who are searching for cheaper
  freelancer.
- If the client has a small job and is searching for a cheaper freelancer.
- You should always write an attractive proposal so that clients will be impressed.

The bottom line is, if the client has a small project and is willing to take some risk on the project, they will go for new freelancer. And you should be cheaper. You should give excellent service to get more and more jobs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my question. I will follow your instructions.